# Calling Delphi DLL in c# "“Attempted to read or write protected memory. " error

Tags: c#, delphi, dll, dllimport

I am trying to import a delphi dll and use its method.

Here is the delphi method signature:

```
function CALinkEncode(SubscriberID, MailshotID, LinkID: DWORD; sCode: PWideChar): HRESULT; stdcall;
```

Here is the c# code to import the dll and use the function.

```
    [DllImport(@"Decoder.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    static extern string CALinkEncode(
        int SubscriberID,
        int MailshotID,
        int LinkID
    );

    public static string CALinkDecodeString(int cas, int cam, int cal)
    {
        string retvalptr = CALinkEncode(cas, cam, cal);

        return retvalptr;
    }
```

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a parameter, have the wrong return type, and have the wrong character set. It should be:

```
[DllImport(@"Decoder.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern uint CALinkEncode(
     uint SubscriberID,
     uint MailshotID,
     uint LinkID,
     string sCode
 );
```

I've assumed the string parameter is an input parameter. If not, then you need to declare it as StringBuilder and pass a StringBuilder instance with sufficient capacity for the output buffer.

.